# Eclipse - Just uninstalled Java 1.7 (still have Java 1.6 on my machine), but now Eclipse won't recognize any java stuff

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm extremely confused about how to set up Java on Eclipse. I don't get how classpath/system variables/etc all works. I set my Java compiler settings from 1.7 to 1.6 after I uninstalled 1.7 (I still have 1.6). But it's still not working. Any help?

Comment: Have you gone to Window>Preferences and set your compiler compliance level to 1.6? Does your project have a project-specific compiler compliance level? Do your settings point to the correct JRE?

Comment: What do you see in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs?

Comment: @Tim was my post useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Eclipse. Follow ***Project => Properties => Java Build Path***.

Come onto ***Libraries*** tab and on the right hand side you will see some buttons, click ***Add Library***.

Select ***JRE System Library*** and click "Next" button. By clicking on Installed JREs button you will see the JREs that your Eclipse recognizes. If the JRE version is not visible there, you can use "Add" button to add a new JRE, and make sure you set the path of new JRE correctly. Sample path on my machine: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6*

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to set up classpath: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html, or may be you have only JRE (not JDK)?